# sometime shadow(elevation) doesn't work in react native

Tags: android, react-native, border, shadow, elevation

In react native elevation not working but if we apply borderWidth there then it starts work. any reason?

i tried applying zIndex, backgroudColor, opacity still facing issue

here is the code:

```
 <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#fff', flex: 1 }}>
 <View style={{
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            marginTop: 10,
            paddingVertical: 22,
            paddingHorizontal: 20,
            alignItems: 'center',
            elevation: 5, // not working
            shadowColor: "#E0E0E0",
          }}>
 <View>
 <Text style={styles.totalText}>Total Amount</Text>
 <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Manrope 
 Bold',fontSize:20}}>selectedIndex?.month</Text>
 </View>
 <PrimaryButton label="Pay Now" onPress={() => onClickPayNowButton()} 
 style={{ width: 128 }} />
 </View>
 </View>
```

Comment: Hi @Shivani Panda can you please share your code?

Comment: @darshilsakhiya added code above. please look